# Let main thread wait async threads complete

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I'm new to c++ and don't know how to let main thread wait for all async threads done. I refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265652/wait-for-async-file-write-to-finish-before-exiting-main-thread) but makes void consume() not parallel.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>     // sleep
#include <future>

using namespace std;

class Myclass {
private:
    std::vector<int> resources;
    std::vector<int> res;

    std::mutex resMutex;
    std::vector<std::future<void>> m_futures;
public:
    Myclass() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) resources.push_back(i);   // add task
        res.reserve(resources.size());
    }

    void consume() {
        for (int i = 0; i < resources.size(); i++) {
            m_futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &Myclass::work, this, resources[i]));
//            m_futures.back().wait();
        }
    }

    void work(int x) {
        sleep(1);     // Simulation time-consuming

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(resMutex);
        res.push_back(x);
        printf("%d be added.---done by %d.\n", x, std::this_thread::get_id());
    }

    std::vector<int> &getRes() { return res;}
};

int main() {
    Myclass obj;
    obj.consume();
    auto res = obj.getRes();
    cout << "Done. res.size = " << res.size() << endl;
    for (int i : res) cout << i << " ";
    cout <<"main thread over\n";
}
```

Main thread ends up when res = 0. I want obj.getRes() be be executed when all results be added into res.

```
Done. res.size = 0
main thread over
4 be added.---done by 6.
9 be added.---done by 11...
```

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea with the commented out line: `m_futures.back().wait();`, you just have it in the wrong place.

As you note, launching a `std::async` and then waiting for its result right after, forces the entire thing to execute in series and makes the async pointless.

Instead you want two functions: One, like your `consume()` that launches all the async's, and then another that loops over the futures and calls `wait` (or `get`, whatever suits your needs) on them - and then call that from `main`.

This lets them all run in parallel, while still making `main` wait for the final result.

Comment: This will be so much easier to do once the concurrency TS makes it to the standard. Doing `when_all(futures).wait();` is all you will need to do.

Comment: Yes, being able to say either "Wait for all" or "Wait for first" on a collection of futures in a simple way would be a great addition.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @Frodyne 's answer,
`consume()` function calls are parallel, and main thread waits for the all `consume()` s have their work done;

```
 void set_wait(void)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < resources.size(); i++) {
            m_futures[i].wait();
        }
    }
```

And call it here

```
    void consume() {
        for (int i = 0; i < resources.size(); i++) {
            m_futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &Myclass::work, this, resources[i]));
             // Calling wait() here makes no sense
        }
        set_wait(); // Waits for all threads do work
    }
```

I created new function for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::future:wait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait) after you add task to `m_futures`. Example.

```
void consume() {
    for (int i = 0; i < resources.size(); i++) {
        m_futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, &Myclass::work, this, resources[i]));
          //m_futures.back().wait();
    }
    for(auto& f: m_futures) f.wait();
}
```